# NOT condition in elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I am trying to implement `NOT` condition in elasticsearch query. 
Can I Implement `filter` inside `bool` or I need to write separate 
filter as below. Any optimum solution is there?

```
{
   "query": {
      "bool": {
     "must": [
        {
           "query_string": {
          "query": "fashion"
           }
        },
        {
           "term": {
          "post_status": "publish"
           }
        }
     ]
      }
   },
   "filter": {
      "not": {
     "filter": {
        "term": {
           "post_type": "page"
        }
     }
      }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use a must_not clause:

```
{
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "must": [
                {
                    "match": {
                        "_all": "fashion"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "term": {
                        "post_status": "publish"
                    }
                }
            ],
            "must_not": {
                "term": {
                    "post_type": "page"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Also, I'd recommend using a match filter instead of query_string, as query_string requires the much more strict Lucene syntax (and is therefor more error prone), whereas match works more like a search box: it will automatically transform a human readable query to a Lucene query.

Comment: I really appreciate your suggestion. But I have tried your solution it does not return any records.

Comment: it seems problem in `match` query to search `fashion` keyword. when I remove `match` query part it returns data.

Comment: Ah, I see: try changing the `query` property of the `match` clause to the name of the field you want to search. If you want to search multiple fields, have a look at [multi_match](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-multi-match-query.html).

Comment: Yeah !! Now working smoothly :) and also I am applicable to mark this as solutions. Thanks a lot @Victor Welling